# VHDL assigning bit inputs to bit vector

Tags: vhdl

In my homework, I have to put in a truth table and get a schematic from it. My code is below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity C0 is
    Port (  a1 : in STD_LOGIC;
            a0 : in STD_LOGIC;
            b1 : in STD_LOGIC;
            b0 : in STD_LOGIC;
            input : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 to 1);
            OutC0 : out STD_LOGIC);
end C0;

architecture Behavioral of C0 is
begin

process (input)
begin
    case input is

       when "0000" => OutC0 <= '0';
       when "0001" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "0010" => OutC0 <= '0';
       when "0011" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "0100" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "0101" => OutC0 <= '0';
       when "0110" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "0111" => OutC0 <= '0';
       when "1000" => OutC0 <= '0';
       when "1001" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "1010" => OutC0 <= '0';
       when "1011" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "1100" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "1101" => OutC0 <= '0';
       when "1110" => OutC0 <= '1';
       when "1111" => OutC0 <= '0';

    end case ; 
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

The problem is that when I get the schematic, there is only one input. Four inputs, `a1`, `a0`, `b1`, and `b0`, should be visible. Somehow, I have to put `a1`, `a0`, `b1`, and `b0` into the vector input. If you recommend another way it would be great too, but not too complicated please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your codes doesn't analyze (compile). A case statement choice must be a locally static value of the case expression which must have a locally static subtype  and has a length of two while your local static choices have a length of four. You obviously want a length of four and the value matching the agreggate value of a1, a0, b1 and b0. Instead of a port input should be an architecture signal with a length of four. The concatenated value of a1, a0, b1, and b0 should be assigned to input in a concurrent signal assignment or separate process. There should also be an others choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one input because only `input` is being used.`a1`, `a0`, `b1` and `b0` are not being used by any process (at least not in the snippet).

When you synthesize the VHDL description, it will trim all signals that are not used. 
This is done in order to save area and power, for example.

The [synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL#Synthesizable_constructs_and_VHDL_templates) of a description to the real hardware is a complex topic and I won't enter in many details.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, your logic does not depend on `a0`, `a1`, `b0` or `b1` signals. Furthermore, the length of the `input` vector should not be 2 but 4.

1. You should remove the `input` vector from the port list in the entity declaration. Make it a four-bit signal: `signal input : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);`. You can check [this link](http://www.vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00064.htm) for more guidance.
2. You probably want that the value of the vector `input` depends on the value of the four `std_logic` signals. Assign the vector a value by concatenating the four signals: `input <= a0 & a1 & b0 & b1;`. Because it's ambiguous from your question in which orders the bits in the vector should be, you probably have to modify this!
3. Also include the `others` choice in your `case` statement.
4. The output seems to be dependent only on the 0th and the 2nd element of the `input` vector in the case statement. So don't get worried if not all of the input are connected when you check the diagram: it's because they just have no effect!

Ps. Some references for further reading might be in place, e.g.: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/ or http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/ for self-learning.

Happy coding.